# How do I 301 redirect - for all urls of my website to one single page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

I have a website: www.example.pro

with pages like: www.example.pro/contact-us/ and www.example.pro/about/

I want every URL from this website to redirect to: www.example.com

Example: when opening www.example.pro/about/

it will redirect to www.example.com (and not to www.example.com/about/ like you might think..)

This is my current HTACCESS:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.pro$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.pro$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think the wordpress rewrites are confusing the matter, move your stuff to above those. Besides that, why are you including $1 in the replacement on the last line? That's only replacing the domain name, and still using the location inside that.

Comment: You could assign a single CGI "handler" to all files on example.pro, and the handler would do the redirect.

Comment: The rule you need is only `RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]` - you don't need to escape the destination like it's a regex, since it's not, [see the docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). This one rule need to be first (with appropriate conditions, which you have), or better in a separate vhost.

Comment: @AD7six  worked! the wordpress stuff was the thing that bothered :) 
thnx!